# Trying to retrieve Data from a GET Request

Tags: ios, swift, networking, get, alamofire

I'm trying to make a GET Request through Alamofire and expect data to be returned. It works fine when I initialize my Data class in my Viewcontroller like

```
 let dataRequest = DataClass()
```

and then call my function to GET Data, but when I try to declare it like

```
 let dataRequest: DataClass!
```

and try to call the GET function
it says unexpectedly found nil.

The reason I'm force unwrapping, versus initializing is because in my Data Class, I have an init function like init(address: String, Zip: Double).

I'll share my Classes so maybe someone can give me some insight as to why its returning nil.

```
class FirstViewController {
var dataRequest: DataClass!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

   dataRequest.downloadData { // Returns nil at this point
    let initData = DataClass(dataRequest._address)


}

 }
}
```

DataClass

```
Class DataClass {
var _address: String!
 init(address: String) {
 _address = address
 }
func downloadProperties(completed: @escaping downloadComplete) {
    Alamofire.request(Listings).responseJSON { response in
        if let result = response.result.value {
            let dict = JSON(result)
            if let data = dict["data"].dictionary {

                if let listingResultDict = data["listings"]?.array  {

                    for list in listingResultDict {

                        if let propertyAddress = list["data"]["name"].string {
                            self._address = propertyName
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              complete()
             }
           }

    }
```

Constans

```
typealias downloadComplete = () -> ()
```

Let me know if there needs to be any more clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never initialized `dataRequest` in `FirstViewController`.

Doing `DataClass!` does not initialize it. It basically tells the compiler that you are guaranteeing that this value is NOT nil and is not optional.

You still have to give it an initial value.. That is why when you do:

`let dataRequest = DataClass()` it works (dataRequest in this case may be optional). You can also do:  `let dataRequest: DataClass! = DataClass()` to tell the compiler that it will NOT be nil and will have an initial value.

Comment: I can't call DataClass without initializing it with the init function though, and the data is empty until I call the downloadProperties function.

Comment: @bradfordgray; What I suggested will work. Otherwise do `dataRequest = Data(...)`  then do `dataRequest.downloadData` AFTER.

Comment: Yes you are correct, I just had to add dummy data into the initial declaration, and then I could call the download and populate everything. Thanks.

Comment: @bradfordgray; you could also make another init() function that sets address to a blank string :)

Answer (score 0):

You have not initialize the

```
dataRequest
```

Before calling the

```
dataRequest.downloadData { ... }
```

you should add

```
dataRequest = DataClass()
```

So that's why it return a nil value

Comment: But if I call dataRequest = DataClass(), it requires me to return the init. The address is empty though before I call downloadData.